# makefile - what to do with the kconfig file

Tags: compiler-construction, linux-kernel, makefile, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I stumbled over this [site](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap#USBTV007_EasyCAP) about USB video grabber under Linux, I'm trying to compile the code found [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/media/usb/usbtv). I have read about makefiles but this one confuses me, cause it's so short:

```
usbtv-y := usbtv-core.o \
    usbtv-video.o

obj-$(CONFIG_VIDEO_USBTV) += usbtv.o
```

I wanted to write now my own makefile. What I want to know now is, what the `Kconfig` file is for and how to use it. I have a hard time finding more information about how to use it, just some stuff regarding KDE which is not what I want. Can someone enlighten me please? I think it's important, cause in the description (on the first site I linked) it says under how to make it work

> Linux kernel driver, enable CONFIG_VIDEO_USBTV

Here's the Kconfig file:

```
config VIDEO_USBTV
        tristate "USBTV007 video capture support"
        depends on VIDEO_V4L2
        select VIDEOBUF2_VMALLOC

        ---help---
          This is a video4linux2 driver for USBTV007 based video capture devices.

          To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
          module will be called usbtv
```

Also, what is meant in the Kconfig file with "choose M here"? Where? How? When?

Comment: These are not complete makefiles, that's why they seem so short.  They are _included_ by other makefiles, and all the guts and magic happens in those.  The module makefiles are small and simple as you say.  However, of course, they can only be used to build code for use in the Linux kernel, not other places.

Comment: Google "linux Kernel module makefile"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Makefile

This Makefile is not complete. It is included by other makefiles:

This makefile [1] includes this one [2] which includes this one [3] which includes this one [4] which includes this one [5] which includes your example.

### Kconfig

Like your Makefile, this Kconfig file is also not complete. It is included by other Kconfig: this kconfig [6] includes ... which includes ... etc ... which includes your example.

According to the documentation, this piece of kconfig defines a help text:

> - help text: "help" or "---help---"
>     This defines a help text. The end of the help text is determined by
>     the indentation level, this means it ends at the first line which has
>     a smaller indentation than the first line of the help text.
>     "---help---" and "help" do not differ in behaviour, "---help---" is
>     used to help visually separate configuration logic from help within
>     the file as an aid to developers.

So, "M" is an option of the program and is not a feature of kconfig. It has nothing to do with Kconfig.

### Documentation

You will find kconfig documentation here [7] and makefile documentation here [8].

### URLs

> [1] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Makefile
>
> [2] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/Makefile
>
> [3] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/Makefile
>
> [4] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/usb/Makefile
>
> [5] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/usb/Makefile
>
> [6] https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Kconfig
>
> [7] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt
>
> [8] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt